# Expectation value of the solution of the Langevin equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, stochastic-processes

The Langevin equation,
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} x = - \gamma x + \sqrt{\gamma} \xi (t)
$$ has the solution
$$
x(t)=e^{-t\gamma}\left(x(0)+\sqrt{\gamma}\int_0^tdt e^{\gamma t}\xi(t)\right)
$$. The expectation value of the solution is given as
$$
\langle x(t) \rangle = e^{-\gamma t} \langle x(0) \rangle
$$. How can I calculate the $\langle x(t)^2 \rangle$ and $\langle x(t)^4 \rangle$?

Comment: Use $\langle\xi(t)\rangle=0$ and $\langle\xi(t)\xi(t')\rangle=c\delta(t-t')$ where the constant $c$ depends on temperature. Is the noise $\xi(t)$ Gaussian? Then you can write also the fourth moment.

Comment: @Christophe Thanks for the response! Could it be possible for you to elaborate a little on the fourth moment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
\langle x_t^2\rangle 
&= \langle x_tx_t \rangle \\
&= \langle \left(x_0e^{-\gamma t} + \sqrt\gamma\int_0^t e^{-\gamma (t-s)}ds \xi(s)\right) \left(x_0e^{-\gamma t} + \sqrt\gamma\int_0^t e^{-\gamma (t-s')}ds' \xi(s')\right) \rangle
\end{align}
$x_0$ and the noise are uncorrelated so
\begin{align}
=(x_0e^{-\gamma t})^2 + \gamma \int_0^t\int_0^t dsds' e^{-\gamma (t-s)}e^{-\gamma (t-s')}\langle\xi(s)\xi(s')\rangle
\end{align}
Since $\langle\xi(s)\xi(s')\rangle = c\delta(s-s')$ we can remove one of the two integrals
\begin{align}
&=(x_0e^{-\gamma t})^2 + c\gamma \int_0^t ds e^{-\gamma (t-s)}e^{-\gamma (t-s)} \\
&=(x_0e^{-\gamma t})^2 + \frac{c}{2}(1-e^{-2\gamma t}) \\
&= \langle x_t\rangle^2 +\frac{c}{2}(1-e^{-2\gamma t})
\end{align}

Since the process is gaussian you find higher moments using Wick's theorem. For example you can find the third and fourth moments by solving
\begin{align}
\langle \left[x_t-\langle x_t\rangle\right]^3\rangle &= 0\\
\langle \left[x_t-\langle x_t\rangle\right]^4 \rangle &= 3 \langle \left[x_t-\langle x_t\rangle\right]^2 \rangle^2
\end{align}

Comment: I think you need to correct the last equation, to account that $x(t)$ has non-zero mean.

Comment: @pp.ch.te $ \langle x(t)^4 \rangle = 3 \langle x(t)^2 \rangle^2 $ is the final result I'll get ??

Comment: @Vadim you're right, I've corrected my answer